# Electrogenic ion transporter

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, terminology

> At the molecular level, electrical current across cell membranes ﬂows through three unique classes of integral membrane proteins (see Chapter 2): ion channels, electrogenic ion transporters, and electrogenic ion pumps.[1](http://One%20class%20of%20electrogenic%20transporters%20includes%20the%20adenosine%20triphosphate%20(ATP)%E2%80%93dependent%20ion%20pumps.)

later it is said:

> One class of electrogenic transporters includes the adenosine triphosphate (ATP)–dependent ion pumps.[2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=HlMJRw08ihgC&pg=PT455&lpg=PT455&dq=One%20class%20of%20electrogenic%20transporters%20includes%20the%20adenosine%20triphosphate%20(ATP)%E2%80%93dependent%20ion%20pumps.&source=bl&ots=2IWD2Fo3YF&sig=3PgT4l8Zg-_CRHs1pd_86bNp2Qw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy-ob-jqLVAhVSO7wKHRkJAnAQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=One%20class%20of%20electrogenic%20transporters%20includes%20the%20adenosine%20triphosphate%20(ATP)%E2%80%93dependent%20ion%20pumps.&f=false)

Is there any fundamental difference between "electrogenic" ion transporter and "electrogenic" ion pump, considering the fact that denosine triphosphate (ATP)–dependent ion pumps are also included in the former?

---

## My attempt:

From [this](http://www.physiologyweb.com/glossary/e/electrogenic.html) site ,Secondary active transporters are electrogenic, so if I consider those as electrogenic ion transporters , then also iam still confused why sodium potassium pump is in the category of ion transporter but not in ion pump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pump and transporter are synonymous: they refer to proteins that, unlike channels, use a form of active transport to move ions or molecules against their concentration gradient, although "pump" is most often used in the context of *primary* pumps, that is, those that directly use ATP, whereas "transporter" is more often used to describe the whole category or *secondary* pumps that use existing gradients.

> then also iam still confused why sodium potassium pump is in the category of ion transporter but not in ion pump

I have no idea where you are getting this statement from, clearly the sodium potassium *pump* is a pump.

[Gadsby, D. C. (2009). Ion channels versus ion pumps: the principal difference, in principle. Nature reviews. Molecular cell biology, 10(5), 344.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2742554/)

Comment: It's from the second source, textbook by boron

Comment: The author is differentiating them as two different entities as in 1st source.

Comment: I don't think so, I think the author is acknowledging that there are proteins commonly known as pumps and those commonly known as transporters (partly by the primary/secondary tendencies of naming, which I mentioned), and intending to be fully comprehensive by listing both terms. It does not imply they are actually separate categories. The only other explanation is that the author is wrong.

Comment: For example, searching google for "humans, mammals, and" returns a paper titled like this: *Influenza type A in humans, mammals and birds: determinants of virus virulence, host-range and interspecies transmission.*: that author certainly isn't making the case that humans are not mammals.

Comment: 3 **unique** classes of integral membrane proteins.....

Comment: I think that's just flowerly prose. Ignore it. They are the same. Textbooks are rarely perfect.